# what's the available graph libraries that can be done using flutter in mobile application?

Tags: graphs

Developing an application that requires graphs in my flutter app. The best graph library that can be helpful to ease my process and make manipulation of graphs easier and interactive.

Answer (score 0):

You want charts_flutter that's developed by Google.

Take a look at [the gallery](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html)